# Separation of Variables; Why are these solutions given?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, differential-equations

Can someone show me a step by step of how you get the solutions in the form of $A \cos$ and $B \sin$ of the equation $y''(x) + k y(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to solve this differential equation is by guessing. For simplicity let's first assume that $k=1$:

$$y''=-y.$$

Now, what function is equal to negative of itself after being differentiated twice? The answer to that is $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ because

\begin{eqnarray}\left(\sin x\right)''&=&\left(\cos x\right)'=-\sin x,\\
\left(\cos x\right)''&=&\left(-\sin x\right)'=-\cos x.\end{eqnarray}

That means any linear combination of sin and cos is a solution to this DE:
$$y(x)=A\sin x+B\cos x.$$

Now for arbitrary $k$ all you need is to insert square root of $k$ into the arguments of trig functions.
$$y(x)=A\sin (\sqrt kx)+B\cos (\sqrt kx).$$

You can check for yourself that after differentiate it twice you'll get your original differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a homogeneous $2^{nd}$-order linear differential equation, thus its general solution can be written as the sum of 2 independent solutions. We usually look for the solutions in the form of $y(x) = A e^{sx}$, whose derivatives are $y'(x) = sA e^{sx}$, $y''(x) = s^2 A e^{sx}$.

Substituting our assumption in the original equation we get

$A e^{sx} ( s^2 + k ) = 0$.

In order to have non-trivial solutions, $A \ne 0$, and thus $s^2 = -k$. Now we have to discern three cases:

1. $k = -c^2 < 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad s_{1,2} = \pm c$: the two independent solutions of the equation read $y_1(x) = A_1 e^{-c x}$,  $y_2(x) = A_2 e^{c x}$ and the general solution of the homogeneous equation reads

$y(x) = y_1(x) + y_2(x) =  A_1 e^{-c x} + A_2 e^{c x}$

2. $k = \omega^2 > 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad s_{1,2} = \pm j \omega$: the two independent solutions of the equation read $y_1(x) = A_1 e^{-i \omega x}$,  $y_2(x) = A_2 e^{j \omega x}$ and the general solution of the homogeneous equation reads

$y(x) = y_1(x) + y_2(x) =  A_1 e^{-j \omega x} + A_2 e^{j \omega x} = 
   A_1 [ \cos( \omega x) - j \sin( \omega x ) ] + A_2 [ \cos( \omega x) + j \sin(\omega)x ]$

in order to have a real solution, $A_1 = {A_2}^* = A_r + j A_i$, and thus

$y(x) = 2A_r \cos(\omega x) + 2 A_i \sin(\omega x) = C_1 \cos(\omega x) + C_2 \sin(\omega x)$.

3. $k = 0$: $y''(x) = 0$$\quad \rightarrow y(x) = Ax + B$.

Then, integration constants are determined using 2 initial or boundary conditions.